# How to read a null terminated String from Data?

Tags: swift, string

An iOS/Swift library delivers a `Data` object containing a null terminated string.
When converting it to a `String` by calling `String(data: dataInstance, encoding: .utf8)`, the returned `String` ends with `"\0"`.
Question now is, how do you convert the `Data` instance to a `String` without having "\0" appended? I.e. how can you omit the null terminating character at the end?

Trying to just `.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)` doesn't have any effect, so your advise is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution: Determine the index of the terminating zero, and convert only the preceding part of the data:

```
let data = Data([65, 66, 0, 67, 0])
let end = data.firstIndex(where: { $0 == 0 }) ?? data.endIndex
if let string = String(data: data[..<end], encoding:.utf8) {
    print(string.debugDescription) // "AB"
}
```

If the data does not contain a null byte then everything will be converted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some pointer operations and use the `init(cString:)` initialiser, which takes a null terminated string.

```
let resultString = data.withUnsafeBytes { buffer in
    guard let pointer = buffer.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self) else { 
        return "" 
    }
    return String(cString: pointer)
}
```

Comment: Pointers... interesting! I thought they extincted from high level languages somewhere in the 90s. ;-) But joke aside, I don't know the iPhone's hw well enough to use them, so @MartinR 's 'find the null character' approach seems safer. Still, thank you very much for sharing this!